# With Picasso, is it still necessary to use it in Asynctask?

Tags: android, image

I've seen many examples of using [*Picasso*](http://square.github.io/picasso/) in AsyncTasks.

But some people say that picasso image loading doesn't requires a AsyncTask since the `Picasso.with(Context).load("url").into(imageview)` passes the call to the worker thread.

So it is still necessary?

Comment: It is possible that there is other functionality being handled in the AsyncTask that makes it useful, but as far as all of the imaging libraries I am aware of, they handle multi-threading for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Picasso handles asynchronous loading.

Answer (score 0):

No, libraries like Picasso, Glide, Fresco, are responsible for controlling the asynchronous process, optimizing and avoiding errors with the UI thread.